# CoordinatorLayout in Activity click issue

Tags: android, sdk, android-coordinatorlayout, collapsable

I have Activity with CoordinatorLayout as parent.This has CollapsableToolbar as child.
When I am in Collapsed state and add a fragment, the Activity is still clickable.
I have added **android:clickable="true"** to fragment and activity but still Activity is clickable.

Thanks

Comment: Set the `android:clickable="true"` for the parent layout of the fragment

Answer (score 0):

When You collapse the layout try adding `coordinatorlayout.setClickable(false);`